# MQTT messages do not survive ActiveMQ Artemis failover

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have a simple 2 node Docker cluster Master/Slave with replication HA (just for testing). Starting the cluster works fine. I can see in the management console I have 1 live & 1 backup server. I send three messages (MQTT protocol) to durable queue. The messages show in the durable queue. I kill the live broker. The backup becomes live, all queues are there but no messages. I have the data directories volume mounted to host.
I have "redistribution-delay and "redelivery-delay" set to 0. Are they different, or version issue?

Desired behavior:
Messages from failed broker exist on backup once it is live. I want new clients to consume messages that were already on the queue.

master `broker.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">
    <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core">

        <bindings-directory>./data/bindings</bindings-directory>

        <journal-directory>./data/journal</journal-directory>

        <large-messages-directory>./data/largemessages</large-messages-directory>

        <paging-directory>./data/paging</paging-directory>


        <!-- Connectors -->
        <connectors>
<!--            <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://localhost:61616</connector>-->

            <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://172.20.0.100:61616?sslEnabled=true;trustStorePath=/var/lib/artemis-instance/trust/artemis0-keystore.jks;trustStorePassword=artemis</connector>
            <connector name="netty-backup-connector">tcp://172.20.0.101:61617?sslEnabled=true;trustStorePath=/var/lib/artemis-instance/trust/artemis1-keystore.jks;trustStorePassword=artemis</connector>
        </connectors>

        <!-- Acceptors -->
        <acceptors>
<!--            <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://localhost:61616</acceptor>-->
            <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://172.20.0.100:61616?sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=/var/lib/artemis-instance/trust/artemis0-keystore.jks;keyStorePassword=artemis</acceptor>
            <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true;allowLinkStealing=false</acceptor>
        </acceptors>

        <cluster-user>xxx</cluster-user>
        <cluster-password>xxx</cluster-password>


        <ha-policy>
            <replication>
                <master>
                    <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
    <!--                    <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>-->
                </master>
            </replication>
        </ha-policy>



        <broadcast-groups>
            <broadcast-group name="my-broadcast-group">
                <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
                <group-port>9876</group-port>
                <broadcast-period>2000</broadcast-period>
                <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
            </broadcast-group>
        </broadcast-groups>
        <discovery-groups>
            <discovery-group name="my-discovery-group">
                <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
                <group-port>9876</group-port>
                <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
            </discovery-group>
        </discovery-groups>
        <cluster-connections>
            <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
                <address>qt3</address>
                <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
                <check-period>1000</check-period>
                <connection-ttl>5000</connection-ttl>
                <min-large-message-size>50000</min-large-message-size>
                <call-timeout>5000</call-timeout>
                <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
                <retry-interval-multiplier>1.0</retry-interval-multiplier>
                <max-retry-interval>5000</max-retry-interval>
                <initial-connect-attempts>-1</initial-connect-attempts>
                <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
                <use-duplicate-detection>false</use-duplicate-detection>
                <message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>
                <max-hops>1</max-hops>
                <confirmation-window-size>32000</confirmation-window-size>
                <call-failover-timeout>30000</call-failover-timeout>
                <notification-interval>1000</notification-interval>
                <notification-attempts>2</notification-attempts>
                <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="my-discovery-group"/>
            </cluster-connection>
        </cluster-connections>
        <security-settings>
            <security-setting match="#">
                <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="createAddress" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="browse" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="manage" roles="guest"/>
            </security-setting>
        </security-settings>
        <addresses>
            <address name="DLQ">
                <anycast>
                    <queue name="DLQ" />
                </anycast>
            </address>
            <address name="ExpiryQueue">
                <anycast>
                    <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
                </anycast>
            </address>
            <address name="qt3">
                <multicast>
                    <queue name="qt3" >
                    <durable>true</durable>
                    </queue>
                </multicast>
            </address>
        </addresses>

        <address-settings>
            <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
            <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
                <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                <redistribution-delay>0</redistribution-delay>
                <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
                <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
                <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            </address-setting>
            <address-setting match="qt3">
                <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                <retroactive-message-count>100</retroactive-message-count>
                <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
                <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
                <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            </address-setting>
            <address-setting match="#">
                <redistribution-delay>0</redistribution-delay>
            </address-setting>
            <!--default for catch all-->
            <address-setting match="#">
                <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>

                <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
                <auto-delete-queues>false</auto-delete-queues>
                <auto-delete-addresses>false</auto-delete-addresses>

                <!-- The size of each page file -->
                <page-size-bytes>10M</page-size-bytes>

                <!-- When we start applying the address-full-policy, e.g paging -->
                <!-- Both are disabled by default, which means we will use the global-max-size/global-max-messages  -->
                <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
                <max-size-messages>-1</max-size-messages>

                <!-- When we read from paging into queues (memory) -->

                <max-read-page-messages>-1</max-read-page-messages>
                <max-read-page-bytes>20M</max-read-page-bytes>

                <!-- Limit on paging capacity before starting to throw errors -->

                <page-limit-bytes>-1</page-limit-bytes>
                <page-limit-messages>-1</page-limit-messages>
            </address-setting>
        </address-settings>
    </core>
</configuration>
```

slave `broker.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">
    <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core">

        <bindings-directory>./data/bindings</bindings-directory>

        <journal-directory>./data/journal</journal-directory>

        <large-messages-directory>./data/largemessages</large-messages-directory>

        <paging-directory>./data/paging</paging-directory>

        <!-- Connectors -->
        <connectors>
<!--            <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://localhost:61617</connector>-->
            <connector name="netty-live-connector">tcp://172.20.0.100:61616?sslEnabled=true;trustStorePath=/var/lib/artemis-instance/trust/artemis0-keystore.jks;trustStorePassword=artemis</connector>
            <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://172.20.0.101:61617?sslEnabled=true;trustStorePath=/var/lib/artemis-instance/trust/artemis1-keystore.jks;trustStorePassword=artemis</connector>
        </connectors>

        <!-- Acceptors -->
        <acceptors>
<!--            <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://localhost:61617</acceptor>-->
            <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://172.20.0.101:61617?sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=/var/lib/artemis-instance/trust/artemis1-keystore.jks;keyStorePassword=artemis</acceptor>

            <acceptor name="mqtt" >tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true;allowLinkStealing=false</acceptor>
        </acceptors>

        <cluster-user>xxx</cluster-user>
        <cluster-password>xxx</cluster-password>



        <ha-policy>
            <replication>
                <slave>
                    <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
                </slave>
            </replication>
        </ha-policy>

        <broadcast-groups>
            <broadcast-group name="my-broadcast-group">
                <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
                <group-port>9876</group-port>
                <broadcast-period>2000</broadcast-period>
                <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
            </broadcast-group>
        </broadcast-groups>
        <discovery-groups>
            <discovery-group name="my-discovery-group">
                <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
                <group-port>9876</group-port>
                <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
            </discovery-group>
        </discovery-groups>
        <cluster-connections>
            <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
               <address>qt3</address>
                <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
                <check-period>1000</check-period>
                <connection-ttl>5000</connection-ttl>
                <min-large-message-size>50000</min-large-message-size>
                <call-timeout>5000</call-timeout>
                <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
                <retry-interval-multiplier>1.0</retry-interval-multiplier>
                <max-retry-interval>5000</max-retry-interval>
                <initial-connect-attempts>-1</initial-connect-attempts>
                <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
                <use-duplicate-detection>false</use-duplicate-detection>
                <message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>
                <max-hops>1</max-hops>
                <confirmation-window-size>32000</confirmation-window-size>
                <call-failover-timeout>30000</call-failover-timeout>
                <notification-interval>1000</notification-interval>
                <notification-attempts>2</notification-attempts>
                <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="my-discovery-group"/>
            </cluster-connection>
        </cluster-connections>
        <security-settings>
            <security-setting match="#">
                <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="createAddress" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="browse" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
                <permission type="manage" roles="guest"/>
            </security-setting>

    </security-settings>
        <addresses>
            <address name="DLQ">
                <anycast>
                    <queue name="DLQ" />
                </anycast>
            </address>
            <address name="ExpiryQueue">
                <anycast>
                    <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
                </anycast>
            </address>
<!--            <address name="qt3">-->
<!--                <multicast>-->
<!--                    <queue name="qt3" >-->
<!--                    <durable>true</durable>-->
<!--                    </queue>-->
<!--                </multicast>-->
<!--            </address>-->
        </addresses>

        <address-settings>
            <address-setting match="#">
                <redistribution-delay>0</redistribution-delay>
            </address-setting>
            <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
            <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
                <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
                <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
                <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            </address-setting>
<!--            <address-setting match="qt3">-->
<!--                <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>-->
<!--                <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>-->
<!--                <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>-->
<!--                <retroactive-message-count>100</retroactive-message-count>-->
<!--                &lt;!&ndash; with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting &ndash;&gt;-->
<!--                <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>-->
<!--                <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>-->
<!--                <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>-->
<!--                <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>-->
<!--                <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>-->
<!--            </address-setting>-->

            <!--default for catch all-->
            <address-setting match="#">
                <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>

                <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
                <auto-delete-queues>false</auto-delete-queues>
                <auto-delete-addresses>false</auto-delete-addresses>

                <!-- The size of each page file -->
                <page-size-bytes>10M</page-size-bytes>

                <!-- When we start applying the address-full-policy, e.g paging -->
                <!-- Both are disabled by default, which means we will use the global-max-size/global-max-messages  -->
                <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
                <max-size-messages>-1</max-size-messages>

                <!-- When we read from paging into queues (memory) -->

                <max-read-page-messages>-1</max-read-page-messages>
                <max-read-page-bytes>20M</max-read-page-bytes>

                <!-- Limit on paging capacity before starting to throw errors -->

                <page-limit-bytes>-1</page-limit-bytes>
                <page-limit-messages>-1</page-limit-messages>
            </address-setting>
        </address-settings>
    </core>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What QoS are you using to send your MQTT messages?

Comment: Just the man I was looking for... lol. I have tried  qos 1 and 2.

Comment: I just tried reproducing this and I couldn't. I based my reproducer on the `replicated-transaction-failover` example that ships with the broker. I sent one MQTT message using `mosquitto_pub -t qt3 -h localhost -p 61616 -n -q 1`. After killing the primary broker I confirmed the message was indeed available on the backup.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the behavior of failover has nothing to do with the `redistribution-delay` or `redelivery-delay` settings.

Comment: @JustinBertram Thanks for your efforts. I just figured it out. It did have to do with the mqtt client. I was using the Mqttx CLI tool just for testing but it did not works as advertised, -- FYI for anyone else. Turns out, sometimes it sent durable messages, other times not so much.
Side note.. I noticed in the artemis Github that the examples are missing/moved. Are they being updated ??

Comment: The examples have been relocated to their own repository (i.e. [`activemq-artemis-examples`](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis-examples)) as part of [ARTEMIS-4533](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-4533).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you're sending your MQTT messages with either QoS 1 or 2. QoS 0 messages are not durable and therefore will not survive a failover.